# TelegramBotAPI Как сделать так, чтобы бот отправлял изображения и их можно было листать inline кнопками?

Tags: python, telegram, бот, telebot

Бот из базы данных отправляет картинки по одной, снизу же имеются кнопки вперёд/назад для перемещения по ним. Видел код на aiogram (снизу), но не понимаю, как переделать для api. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
    {
        "slug": "apples",
        "display_name": "Яблоки",
        "image_url": "https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/199/33/68/iStock-1158470655_d_850.jpg"
    },
    {
        "slug": "oranges",
        "display_name": "Апельсины",
        "image_url": "https://www.gastronom.ru/binfiles/images/20141003/b3c0313e.jpg"
    },
    {
        "slug": "bananas",
        "display_name": "Бананы",
        "image_url": "https://elorda.info/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/banana-health-big.jpg"
    },
    {
        "slug": "lemons",
        "display_name": "Лимоны",
        "image_url": "https://ont.by/static/article/big/index/BWLqeb0F5qwrITqE.jpg"
    },
]

fruits_callback = CallbackData("Fruits", "page")


def get_fruits_keyboard(page: int = 0) -> InlineKeyboardMarkup:
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    has_next_page = len(fruits) > page + 1

    if page != 0:
        keyboard.add(
            InlineKeyboardButton(
                text="< Назад",
                callback_data=fruits_callback.new(page=page - 1)
            )
        )

    keyboard.add(
        InlineKeyboardButton(
            text=f"• {page + 1}",
            callback_data="dont_click_me"
        )
    )

    if has_next_page:
        keyboard.add(
            InlineKeyboardButton(
                text="Вперёд >",
                callback_data=fruits_callback.new(page=page + 1)
            )
        )

    return keyboard


@dp.message_handler(commands=["fruits"])
async def fruits_index(message: Message):
    fruit_data = fruits[0]
    caption = f"Вы выбрали <b>{fruit_data.get('display_name')}</b>"
    keyboard = get_fruits_keyboard()  # Page: 0

    await bot.send_photo(
        chat_id=message.chat.id,
        photo=fruit_data.get("image_url"),
        caption=caption,
        parse_mode="HTML",
        reply_markup=keyboard
    )


@dp.callback_query_handler(fruits_callback.filter())
async def fruit_page_handler(query: CallbackQuery, callback_data: dict):
    page = int(callback_data.get("page"))

    fruit_data = fruits[page]
    caption = f"Вы выбрали <b>{fruit_data.get('display_name')}</b>"
    keyboard = get_fruits_keyboard(page)

    photo = InputMedia(type="photo", media=fruit_data.get("image_url"), caption=caption)

    await query.message.edit_media(photo, keyboard)
```

Comment: Для какого API? Опишите в вопросе подробнее что вы хотите сделать и что не получилось

Comment: В названии написано - TelegramBotAPI, библиотека. У меня не получается сделать эти кнопки конкретно на этой библиотеке.

Comment: это довольно непростая задача, я решил ее с помощью библиотеки python-telegram-bot-pagination. поэкспериментируйте с ней https://github.com/ksinn/python-telegram-bot-pagination

Comment: Подключение двух библиотек одновременно?

Comment: @lolkalw пагинатор это просто вспомогательная библиотека для создания кнопок пагинации в телеграм боте, она не устанавливает соединение по токену. так что можете смело подключать

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!